# Cannot cross-compile Qt 5.7 for Raspberry PI because it "requires a C++11 compiler"

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2

I want to cross compile qt5 on RPi2 according to this [RaspberryPi2EGLFS](http://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) when I want to configure in step7 I see this error and I don't have any idea how to solve it.

```
.
.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:91: recipe for target 'c++11' failed
make: *** [c++11] Error 1
C++11 disabled.
ERROR: Qt requires a C++11 compiler and yours does not seem to be that.
Please upgrade.
```

I use antergos x64.

Comment: And what compiler are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: are you really using qt5.6 or have you just downloaded the most recent one, qt5.7? Imho, qt5.6 doesn't use c++11 language features, while qt5.7 does. So if you really have a compiler that doesn't support c++11, I'd stay with qt5.6

Comment: Same problem, when using Qt 5.7. The compiler is the one suggested on the site linked in the question: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools .  There are 5 compilers in that package, and the tutorial recommends `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian`